# How to underlay circle with mogrify in one command

Tags: imagemagick, mogrify

I wrote this script and it's working fine, but I would like to do all of it in one step on the fly, without the extra temp image.

explanation: i have a lot of broken image files and i want to draw a circle underneath each image. for this i have to create a temporary image circle.png and then use "image DstOver" to place it below each of the images:

```
convert -size 200x200 xc:transparent -fill red -draw 'translate 100,100 circle 0,0 100,0' circle.png
mogrify -draw "image DstOver 0,0 0,0 'circle.png'" images/*.png
```

Something along the lines of:

```
mogrify -fill red -draw "DstOver translate 100,100 circle 0,0 100,0" images/*.png
```

But this is always giving me an error, no matter where i place the DstOver:

```
mogrify: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `DstOver' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/3169.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composition operators like "DstOver" are only used with the "image" primitive of "-draw".  Just omit it. See the "-draw" entry in the ImageMagick [commandline](http://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#draw) documentation.

You can have multiple "-draw " options, some drawing figures such as "circle ..." and others such as "image DstOver ...".

Comment: oh, so i cannot put anything below my images with mogrify? maybe with an image defined as xc: ?

Comment: Yes, it's a limitation of -draw that it doesn't accept the composite_operator except with the "image" primitive, and that -draw ignores the global compose operator.  And it's a limitation of mogrify that it doesn't accept the -compose option.  Either or both would be useful features to add to *Magick.

Comment: well, nice to see that even such a badass tool is not capable of everything .. (yet). At least I can work with the temporary image, so still a cool thing! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but in general, `mogrify` will have trouble doing anything with `multi-image operators` or `stack operators`. The only exception I know of is the `-draw image` operator, so you need to create your image up-front and then use that:

```
# Blue rectangle with transparent centre
convert -size 200x200 xc:none -bordercolor blue -border 50 start.png
```

[image]

```
# Your circle
convert -size 200x200 xc:white -fill red -draw 'translate 100,100 circle 0,0 100,0' circle.png
```

[image]

```
# Now underlay
mogrify -draw "image DstOver 0,0 0,0 'circle.png'" start.png
```

[image]

Comment: yeah, that's what i'm already doing, see the code in the question. thx for the detailed explanation anyway!

Comment: just read my question and added an explanation what it is actually doing, sorry ;)